# How can you read a previous file within a directory in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, buffer

Let's say I have multiple files. I want to loop through all of them and always read 2 files: previous one and the current one. 
I do not want to read files simultaneously: read the previous one in respect to the current file. 
So first I read the first file (well, this one is an exception since the previous file does not exist for it). Then 1st and 2nd. Then 2nd and 3rd. Then 3rd and 4th and so on.

Comment: what do you want to do with the two file contents? how big are these files? small enough to read them both into memory at the same time?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle they are max 512 kB. I want to read the files line by line and look for regex matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```py
prev = None
for fpath in files_iter:
  if prev is not None:
    "<read previous>"
  "<read current>"
  prev = fpath
```